# Index out of Bounds Error?

Tags: c#, database, loops, indexing

So I am developing an application that requires I iterate through all entries and update remind dates and match serial keys with every user.  For some reason I get an out of bounds error even though I am not iterating past all known index

```
public void updateReminders(RichTextBox rtb, RichTextBox rtb2, DataTable d1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ChildRoot.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {

            dr = d1.Rows[i];
            TreeNode tn = ChildRoot.Nodes[i];

            DateTime dtCal = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["NEXTCONTACT"]);
            DateTime dtCalTime = dtCal.AddDays(60);

            string clientName = tn.Nodes[0].Text;
            string clientNameTrimmed = clientName.Split(new string[] { "NAME: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();

            if(dtCalTime <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                rtb.AppendText("Calibration Client: " + clientNameTrimmed + " is due for a call! " + dtCal + Environment.NewLine);
                rtb2.AppendText("Calibration Client: " + clientNameTrimmed + " is due for a call! " + dtCal + Environment.NewLine);
                tn.Nodes[4].Text = "NEXT CONTACT: " + DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();

                dr = dts1.Rows[i];
                dr["NEXTCONTACT"] = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
                dr["LASTCONTACT"] = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
                dr.AcceptChanges();

                string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(currentPath, "AppData")))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(currentPath, "AppData"));
                }

                try
                {
                    string savePath = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\AppData\ClientHistory_Calibration.ini");
                    string notePath = "Calibration Client: " + clientNameTrimmed + " is due for a call! " + dtCal;
                    string[] lines = { notePath };

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(savePath, lines);
                    MessageBox.Show("Remind History has automatically been saved to 'Install directory/AppData/ClientHistory_Calibration.ini'", "Saved!");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception message:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 3.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at ClientDataBase.Code.ClientTreeNodeView.updateReminders(RichTextBox rtb, RichTextBox rtb2, DataTable d1) in c:\Users\AdamSMI\Desktop\DatabaseTest\ClientDataBase\ClientDataBase\Code\ClientTreeNodeView.cs:line 541
   at ClientDataBase.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\AdamSMI\Desktop\DatabaseTest\ClientDataBase\ClientDataBase\Code\Form1.cs:line 57
```

Comment: Why would `i < ChildRoot.Nodes.Count` be a valid guard for `d1.Rows[i];` ?

Comment: Do you know what line the out of bounds error occurs on? Is it throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Comment: Use a debugger or at least post the Exception info with the stacktrace.

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 3.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at ClientDataBase.Code.ClientTreeNodeView.updateReminders(RichTextBox rtb, RichTextBox rtb2, DataTable d1) in c:\Users\AdamSMI\Desktop\DatabaseTest\ClientDataBase\ClientDataBase\Code\ClientTreeNodeView.cs:line 541
   at ClientDataBase.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\AdamSMI\Desktop\DatabaseTest\ClientDataBase\ClientDataBase\Code\Form1.cs:line 57

Comment: Can't you use the debugger and tell us the line where the exception is trown?

Comment: Don't add information in comments, use the _edit_ link to improve your questions. You can then also format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while you checked the count in `ChildRoot.Nodes`, you did *not* check for the number of `Row`s in `dt` OR `dtsl` - judging by the error message specifically mentioning `row at position 3`, one of these is the culprit. Make sure you're checking for the row to exist - if it doesn't it may be a problem keeping those in sync somewhere in your application, or you might need to add it as the code executes, instead of retrieving it.

Comment: Thank you Aravol for a proper response.  I fixed the problem thanks to your solution.